# SNOWFLAKE: Invalid argument types for function 'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216)) At Statement.execute snowflake

Tags: snowflake-cloud-data-platform

I am running a stored procedure in snowflake and the code compilation is failing with

```
Execution error in store procedure SP_POPULATE_SYS_AUDIT_DATA_BMC: SQL compilation error: error line 6 at position 2,776 Invalid argument types for function 'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216)) At Statement.execute, line 150 position 61
```

below is the code snippet where the error occurs

```
v_sql_3 = `insert into `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_source_table_name+`_temp
                        (sys_id, documentkey,tablename,fieldname,value, sys_created_on, action, sys_updated_on, sys_created_by ,
                            sys_updated_by, sourceinstance, cdctype,_numerify_batchid, cdchash, cdchash_sequence, cdctime, etl_run_number)
                        select concat(`+v_sys_id_field+`,'~',replace('`+v_field+`',' ','_')) as sys_id, 
                            original_request_id as documentkey,'`+v_source_table_name+`' as tablename, '`+v_field+`' as fieldname, 
                            
                            trim(replace(replace(`+v_sql_2+`concat(case when split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2) 
                                then substring(split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2),1,
                                position('(',split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2))-1) 
                                else split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2) end ,': '),
                                `+v_sql_1+`': ',''),'\n','')) as value, audit_date as sys_created_on, 
                            case when action = 4 then 'Create' when action = 2 then 'Set'  when action = 8 then  'Delete'  when action = 16 then  'Merge' end,
                            modified_date as sys_updated_on,submitter as sys_created_by, user as sys_updated_by,sourceinstance,cdctype as cdctype ,
                            _numerify_batchid, cdchash, cdchash_sequence, cdctime , `+v_etl_run_number+` 
                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
                        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%'
                    union
                        select concat(`+v_sys_id_field+`,'~',replace('`+v_field+`',' ','_')) as sys_id, 
                            original_request_id as documentkey,'`+v_source_table_name+`' as tablename, '`+v_field+`' as fieldname,
                            trim(replace(replace(`+v_sql_2+`concat(case when split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2) REGEXP '.*\\([0-9]\\).*' 
                                then substring(split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2),1,
                                position('(',split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2))-1) 
                                else split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2) end ,': '),
                                `+v_sql_1+`': ',''),'\n','')) as value, audit_date as sys_created_on, 
                            case when action = 4 then 'Create' when action = 2 then 'Set'  when action = 8 then  'Delete'  when action = 16 then  'Merge' end,
                            modified_date as sys_updated_on,submitter as sys_created_by, user as sys_updated_by,sourceinstance,'X' as cdctype ,
                            _numerify_batchid, cdchash, cdchash_sequence, cdctime , `+v_etl_run_number+` 
                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_audit_table_name+`_final 
                        where original_request_id in (select distinct original_request_id 
                                                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
                                                        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%' ) 
                            and fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%'
                            and `+v_sys_id_field+` not in ( select  v_sys_id_field 
                                                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
                                                        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%')`;
            
            snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: v_sql_3} ).execute();
```

PS: I am very new to snowflake

Comment: There's no `iff` in the query pasted - maybe the problem comes from somewhere else?

Comment: there is no IFF in the whole code, I assumed some built-in function is using IFF (something like position or split_part)

Comment: the simple `CASE WHEN x THEN y ELSE z END` is converted to `IFF` by the compiler

Answer (score 3, accepted):

the problem here is, compared to MySQL:

```
select IF(1,TRUE,FALSE); -- this works
```

but in snowflake:

```
select IFF(1,TRUE,FALSE); -- this fails
```

instead the correct way is

```
select IFF(1= 1,TRUE,FALSE); -- this works
```

so be it case or IFF it must be evaluated against some truth value else the compilation fails

same is the problem in the above mentioned code case when is not evaluated against any thing twice and hence the error

Comment: which is what I said in my comment.

Answer (score 2):

the problem is this line

```
case when action = 4 then 'Create' when action = 2 then 'Set'  when action = 8 then  'Delete'  when action = 16 then  'Merge' end
```

should have an `AS action` on the end
as the prior line is `sys_created_on` and the later line is `sys_updated_on`

after the the `etl_run_number` line should be named also.

so if my editing is correct

```
s1 = 'split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2)';

v_sql_3 = `insert into `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_source_table_name+`_temp
        (sys_id, documentkey,tablename,fieldname,value, sys_created_on, 
        action, sys_updated_on, sys_created_by, sys_updated_by, 
        sourceinstance, cdctype,_numerify_batchid, cdchash, 
        cdchash_sequence, cdctime, etl_run_number)
        select concat(`+v_sys_id_field+`,'~',replace('`+v_field+`',' ','_')) as sys_id, 
            original_request_id as documentkey,
            '`+v_source_table_name+`' as tablename,
            '`+v_field+`' as fieldname,
            trim(replace(replace(`+v_sql_2+`concat(
                case when '+s1+' IS NOT NULL
                then substring('+s1+',1,position('(','+s1+')-1) 
                else '+s1+' end ,': '),
                `+v_sql_1+`': ',''),'\n','')) as value,
            audit_date as sys_created_on, 
            case when action = 4 then 'Create' when action = 2 then 'Set'  when action = 8 then  'Delete'  when action = 16 then  'Merge' end as action,
            modified_date as sys_updated_on,
            submitter as sys_created_by, 
            user as sys_updated_by,
            sourceinstance,
            cdctype as cdctype,
            _numerify_batchid, 
             cdchash,
             cdchash_sequence, 
             cdctime , 
             `+v_etl_run_number+` as etl_run_number 
        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%'
    union
        select concat(`+v_sys_id_field+`,'~',replace('`+v_field+`',' ','_')) as sys_id, 
            original_request_id as documentkey,
            '`+v_source_table_name+`' as tablename,
            '`+v_field+`' as fieldname,
            trim(replace(replace(`+v_sql_2+`concat(case when '+s1+' REGEXP '.*\\([0-9]\\).*' 
                then substring('+s1+',1,
                position('(','+s1+')-1) 
                else '+s1+' end ,': '),
                `+v_sql_1+`': ',''),'\n','')) as value,
            audit_date as sys_created_on, 
            case when action = 4 then 'Create' when action = 2 then 'Set'  when action = 8 then  'Delete'  when action = 16 then  'Merge' end as action,
            modified_date as sys_updated_on,
            submitter as sys_created_by,
            user as sys_updated_by,
            sourceinstance,
            'X' as cdctype ,
            _numerify_batchid, 
            cdchash, 
            cdchash_sequence, 
            cdctime , 
            `+v_etl_run_number+` as etl_run_number 
        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_audit_table_name+`_final 
        where original_request_id in (select distinct original_request_id 
                                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
                                        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%' ) 
            and fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%'
            and `+v_sys_id_field+` not in ( select  v_sys_id_field 
                                        from `+v_mds_db_name+`.`+v_mds_table_name+` 
                                        where fields_changed like '%;`+v_field+`;%' and log like '%`+v_field_lookup+`%')`;
    
        snowflake.createStatement( { sqlText: v_sql_3} ).execute();
```

should be what you want.

I extracted

```
split_part(substring(log,position('`+v_field_lookup+`',log)+`+v_field_length+`),': ',2)
```

into a variable called s1 to make it all more readable, as that was massively repeated.

Comment: No luck still got the same error
`
'IFF': (VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216), VARCHAR(16777216)) At Statement.execute, line 196 position 57
`

Comment: @koushikkirugulige well you have 4 case statements. but they are doubled. You can prove it not the `action` one is too complex to turn into an IFF. So it has to be the first. You are effectively passing the output of a SPLIT function to a LOGICAL test, thus that will cause problems. purhaps you need to add a IS NOT NULL test

Comment: the problem is case when X then Y else Z end fails in snowflake it should be case when X is NOT NULL then Y else Z end